# Idiomatic "First Last" => "Last, First" in Java

Tags: java, string, sorting, substring

I am mostly a Python programmer, learning some Java. I needed a function to turn strings containing names in the form "First Last" into "Last, First" (I also need this to be able to handle single names: "Cher" => "Cher" and First Middle Last: "John F. Kennedy" => "Kennedy, John F.") and I started thinking about solving it like I would in Python:

```py
def tolastfirst(astring):
    parts = astring.split()
    return parts[-1] + ", " + " ".join(parts[:-1])
```

String slicing and list splitting and joining are so common and concise in Python that this was the first thing that came to mind. That translated to Java something like this:

```java
public static String toLastFirst(String firstLast) {
    List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(firstLast.split(" "));
    if (parts.size() > 1) {
        String last = parts.get(parts.size() - 1);
        List<String> frontParts = parts.subList(0, parts.size() - 1);
        String front = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(frontParts.toArray(), " ");
        return last + ", " + front;
    } else {
        return firstLast;
    }
}
```

So that seems needlessly complex, and it's probably obvious from the code that I don't understand the whys and wherefores of using an Array vs. a List. It did seem silly to be converting from an Array to a List and back again, so I tried this:

```java
public static String toLastFirst(String firstLast) {
    String[] parts = firstLast.split(" ");
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        String last = parts[parts.length - 1];
        String[] frontParts = Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 0, parts.length - 1);
        String front = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(frontParts, " ");
        return last + ", " + front;
    } else {
        return firstLast;
    }
}
```

Finally, I asked a coworker who actually knows Java, and he suggested that he'd be much more likely to just look for the last space and slice up the string, skipping the whole List/Array business:

```java
public static String toLastFirst(String firstLast) {
    if (firstLast.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
        Integer lastSpace = firstLast.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String first = firstLast.substring(0, lastSpace);
        String last = firstLast.substring(lastSpace, firstLast.length());
        return last + ", " + first;
    } else {
        return firstLast;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Did I have the right intuition switching from using a List to array?
- Is my coworker's suggestion of doing direct string manipulation the most idiomatic way of solving this problem in Java?
- Is the string manipulation approach more efficient (memory, speed?) than the list/array approach?

Mostly I am interested in the second question; I would like to learn to write Java like a native rather than like a Python expat.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this much much shorter using [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
public static String toLastFirst(String firstLast) {
    return firstLast.replaceAll("(.*) (.*)", "$2, $1");
}
```

This should work exactly like your implementations. If the string contains a space, the expression will match, and switch the first and second part, and add a `,`. If it doesn't contain a space, the string remains unchanged.

Comment: I edited the question to note that my use case includes single names like "Cher" => "Cher" and also names with middle name: "Philip Seymour Hoffman" => "Hoffman, Philip Seymour" ... does your solution cover these cases?

Comment: Changing the regex to "(.*) (.*)" does what I need here. Cool.

Comment: @ben: Yes, I was just going to say that. :) Making the first part greedy makes sure that the only exchange made is at the last space.

Answer (score 1):

In general when you don't need to resize then an array can be easier to work with. You certainly want to avoid mixing arrays and lists, try and use one or the other but not mix them.

The direct manipulation is how I would solve this, since you have the specific case of only two halves. @Keppil's answer is probably the neatest Java solution though.

The direct String manipulation will be marginally faster as the Array/List do not need creating, initializing, updating, etc. The difference would be tiny in absolute terms though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public static String toLastFirst(String firstLast) {
    //split on one ore more space chars
    String[] data = firstLast.split("\\s+");
    //need to check length of array etc.
    return data[1] + ", " + data[0];  //build new string
}
```

Comment: Does this cover the use case "Philip Seymour Hoffman" => "Hoffman, Philip Seymour"?

Comment: It's pretty similar to my second attempt, no?

Comment: @benauthor - for that problem, consider looping over `data` from `i<data.length-1` to `i=0`, building up a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object initialized with `data[data.length-1]`